# Many-to-many distinct query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following case: I have two models: UserGroup and User (with a many-to-many relationship). I need to end up with a distinct list of Users.

**What I have: A set of ids of UserGroups, and A set of ids of Users.**

**What I want: A set of distinct list of Users, based upon what I have.**

[image: Relation case]

The illustration is a bit misleading, as it only shows that I have UserGroup ids, but I also have some ids of Users.

How can this be done in an elegant way in Ruby on Rails?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope it helps you

```
user_groups = UserGroup.includes(:users).where('query for your selected user_groups records')
distinct_users = user_groups.collect{|ug|ug.users.collect(&:id)}.flatten.uniq
```

With this, you can get distinct users only for your selected user_groups